# Twitter API request for images with DUKT twitter

Tags: plugin-dukttwitter

I am using DUKT's Twitter 1.0.32 but am fresh at reading APIs, so would like a little help. 
I would like to request tweets with image only from our main ID.

```
 {% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', {count:3}) %}
```

This works fine, but even an attempt to play around with the other parameters within user_timeline baffles me.

Could I ask for some examples to display tweet text & image, plus some other relevant parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used it like this. You can find the documentation for most fields on [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets). Truth be told, the DUKT documentation is not too transparent.

```
{% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { user_id:'', count: 10, trim_user: false }) %}
{% if tweets %}
    <ul class="tweet__list">
        {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <li">
           <img src="{{ tweet.user.profile_image_url }}" alt="">
           <p>{{tweet.text|autoLinkTweet}}</p>
           <span class="date">{{ tweet.created_at | twitterTimeAgo )}</span>        
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

**Update**

You have several entities in the data you get back from Twitter API (as described by Twitter):  media, urls, user_mentions, hashtags, and symbols. The DUKT plugin, however only gives back urls, user_mentions, hashtags, and symbols as far as I see in the error messages they provide.

```
 {{tweet.entities}}
```

Comment: Bedankt Jan, the {{ tweet.created_at)} tag renders an error, but I am looking for the tag which produces the tweeted image, not the user profile image.

Comment: I have tried all sorts of combos with             <img src="{{tweet.media_url_https}}" alt=""> and             <img src="{{tweet.media_url}}" alt=""> but neither work....

Comment: updated the answer and the created_at tag ;)

Comment: Thanks again, Jan your answer explains the deafening silence by DUKT. The image tag is the main feature by my client, so no use for this plugin then.....

Comment: Found an answer on this thread; (http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/is-it-possible-to-get-a-tweet-image-when-using-twitter-plugin)