# Problem pulling Tweets with media using Dukt's Twitter API plugin

Tags: image, plugin-dukttwitter

```
{% set tweets = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { tweet_mode:'extended' }) %}

{% for tweet in tweets %}
    <li>

    {% if tweet.extended_entities.media is defined %}
        {% for item in tweet.extended_entities.media if item.type == 'photo' %}
            <img src="{{ item.media_url }}">
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Anything obviously wrong here? I tested the API with a {{ dump(tweets) }} which seems fine.

[This](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/is-it-possible-to-get-a-tweet-image-when-using-twitter-plugin/27302?noredirect=1#comment35764_27302) thread describes a similar issue but without a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The return from [`craft.twitter.get()`](https://docs.dukt.net/twitter/v2/craft-twitter.html#get-uri-query-headers-options-enablecache-cacheexpire) is not an array of tweets, but a response object, where the actual tweets are nested in an attribute called `data`.

Not tested, but from looking at the plugin docs, something like this should do it:

```
{% set response = craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { tweet_mode:'extended' }) %}

{% if response.success %}
    {% for tweet in response.data %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, Mats. The images are showing now, albeit unlimited versions from each, per list item line. Not sure how to limit the output when a for loop includes a conditional...

Comment: @Nutmeg Not sure I follow, sorry. If you're talking about limiting the number of tweets, you could use the `count` parameter, i.e. `craft.twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', { tweet_mode: 'extended', count: 5 })`.